# Shortest path using less than or equal to m edges in a directed, weighted graph with negative cycles

Tags: graphs

I'm solving a problem:

> Given a directed, weighted graph $G$ that has $V$ vertices (vertex $0$, vertex $1$, ... ,  vertex $(V - 1)$) and $E$ edges and a positive integer $m$, describe an algorithm that finds the length of the shortest path from vertex $0$ to vertex $(V - 1)$ using less than or equal to $m$ edges. Note that the graph may contain negative cycles. If there is no such path, print "N" for that case.

First, I tried Bellman-Ford algorithm, but I cannot deal with negative cycles. Next, I tried one using recursive DFS, but it takes too much time! I think dynamic programming may solve this problem, but I don't know how to start with DP. Is there any fancy way to solve this problem in short time?

Comment: @HEKTO I missed a condition in the problem. Sorry for that. I've edited it.

Comment: I think you need to clarify more... Talking about negative cycles - do you consider solutions, which may include negative cycles as well? If yes, that this solution will be not a path, but a *walk* - please see definitions of these terms. And this path/walk must be directed, right? Also, you probably mean *minimum total weight*, not a shortest one... Please be precise, otherwise you won't get good answers